# Calling a function in MySQL database with table alias

Tags: mysql, database, function

Currently I have used imported a MySQL database in my current environment.My MySQL version is 5.6.x. Now I have certain database functions that I have to use in my java application. The problem is stated below:

1. MySQL database is `EMPLOYEE`.
2. MySQL function `FN_GET_USER_CODE(userID INT)` has used table
   alias `(EMPDTL)` for table `EMP_DETAILS_COMPANY` and used some joins in function definition.
3. When I try to call the function via command 
   `select FN_GET_USER_CODE(234599)`, It says Table `EMPLOYEE.EMPDTL` does not exist.
4. `Error Code: 1146
   Table 'EMPLOYEE.EMPDTL' doesn't exist`

**Function Definition**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`192.168.0.1` FUNCTION `FN_GET_USER_DETAILS(userID INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(25) CHARSET utf8
BEGIN
    DECLARE user_getempcode VARCHAR(100);
    SELECT DISTINCT(reg.empcode) INTO user_getempcode FROM m_registration_seq_num  AS reg
    INNER JOIN EMP_SECRET_CODE ecd
    ON reg.tempcd = ecd.secretcd AND reg.lang_cd = ecd.lang_cd
    RETURN user_getempcode;
END$$
```

DELIMITER ;

Can anyone has idea of what I am missing here.

Comment: Please share FN_GET_USER_DETAILS code

Comment: function code added!

Comment: i have provided a answer please check

Answer (score -1):

I think you are missing `AS` before alias name of table `EMP_SECRET_CODE` . it should be like this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`192.168.0.1` FUNCTION `FN_GET_USER_DETAILS(userID INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(25) CHARSET utf8
BEGIN
    DECLARE user_getempcode VARCHAR(100);
    SELECT DISTINCT(reg.empcode) INTO user_getempcode FROM m_registration_seq_num  AS reg
    INNER JOIN EMP_SECRET_CODE AS ecd
    ON reg.tempcd = ecd.secretcd AND reg.lang_cd = ecd.lang_cd
    RETURN user_getempcode;
END$$
```

Comment: Adding 'AS' isn't mandatory as mysql/oracle automatically treats it as an alias.Actually that was a sample code I have given above. You can check the actual script here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2NllJPwZg04VlVsRzRHaWdzeE0/view

Comment: Issue resolved. Inside update snippet, there was a table missing in my database and that's why the issue was encountered to top level only while the missing table was inside subquery. Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: Incidentally, note that DISTINCT is not a function

Comment: Guys please don't down cast vote for answer i have provided this answer on available code. later he provided detail code and solution it self. @k10gaurav